# Formula with Recursion (n+(n-1)+n) error

Tags: java, recursion

I need to use recursion to calculate how many medals a player gets for example if I enter 3 the player got 8 medals [Ex1.(3+(3-1)+3)=(3+2+3)=8]/[Ex2.(5+(5-1)+5)=(5+4+5)=14] When I enter 1 on the main method to test it works but when I change a number greater than 1 it crashes and I get red letters as error this is the error I get. I have done about 5 recursion methods already but I'm stuck on this one.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at RecursiveFunctions.countMedals(RecursiveFunctions.java:87)
```

---

```
public class RecursiveFunctions{
        public static int countMedals(int n){
            if(n==0){
              return 1+(1-1)+1;
            }
            else{
              return countMedals((n)+(n-1)+(n));
            }

     public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Number of Medals: " + RecursiveFunctions.countMedals(3));
      }
}
```

Comment: Why is this a recursive call?

Comment: Rule # 1: Use an IDE debugger and trace through your code BEFORE posting a question here.  You could have easily found the reason yourself by doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try tracing through the function to see what happens:

```
countMedals(3) returns countMedals(3 + 2 + 3)
countMedals(8) returns countMedals(8 + 7 + 8)
```

This is going to continually grow, and never hit your base case of 0.

Comment: I'having trouble finding the base case in this case I dont know if n ==1 or n==0. Can you explain me why it doesnt hit the base case. Im new to recursion and Im still learning the logic.

Comment: The "base case" is something that a recursive function should always eventually hit. You have the base case set to `n==0` (because this is where recursion stops), but the numbers only become greater and greater so they never hit this case. When you call a method recursively, it's just like calling it normally, so imagine your method restarting at the top over and over but with bigger numbers every time, which is caused by `countMedals((n)+(n-1)+(n))`. Hope this helps.

Comment: So I cannot use recursion in this problem because it keeps looping and  never reaches my base case. I would ask this to my teacher next time.

Answer (score 4):

Your formula has no recursive logic. There is no iteration, it's just a simple math equation.

```
public static int countMedals(int n){ return 3*n - 1;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You recursive method has no endpoint in the recursive calls. 
You call:

```
countMedals((n)+(n-1)+(n))
```

If n is 2, this expression evaluates:

```
countMedals((2)+(2-1)+(2)) -> countMedals(5)
```

And this is:

```
countMedals((5)+(5-1)+(5)) ->  countMedals(14)
```

And so on... You never stop. So you stack is full, and Java crashes.

Answer (score 2):

From your code, it looks like you will never reach the case where `n == 0`. This is why you are entering infinite recursion.

Each time you call your function with `n + (n - 1) + n`, which is essentially `3n - 1`. So what you have is `f(n) = 3n - 1`, and you're passing the result of that into the function itself. Now `f(n) = 0` only when `n = 1 / 3`. Can you see any way where `n` can ever be `1 / 3`?

Also, try plotting this function on a graph. What do you see happening to the `y` values as you keep increasing `x` (basically `n` in this case)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how you can apply recursion like this. To compute f(n) you need to compute f(3n-1), for which you need to compute f(f(3n-1)), etc. It never terminates, so you get a stack overflow.

In fact I don't know why you are recursing at all, if f(3) and f(5) both = 3n-1. Evidently you haven't understood your problem correctly.

Comment: We were told to use recursion for all the signatures. Im new to recursion. Im still learning the logic of recursion.

Comment: But it isn't a recursive formula, as you've described it here. There is no such thing as a 'recursive signature', only recursive implementations.